# How can I load my data before the component is loaded?

Tags: reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am getting the data from the firebase database but am unable to show the data as the component is being executed first and then the data is being load. How can I fix this the proper way? The data loading part is working completely fine just that my map function is loading first and the data is loading after so it isn't being displayed.

```
import Navbar from '../../components/navbar/navbar'
import './playlist.css'
import {useEffect, useState } from 'react'
import album from '../../assets/album1.jpeg'
import { collection, getDocs ,query, where} from 'firebase/firestore'
import { db ,storage} from '../../config/firebase'
import { getDownloadURL, ref } from "firebase/storage";
import { useNavigate,useParams } from 'react-router'
import SongDetail from '../../components/song-detail/songDetail'
function Playlist(){
    const navigate = useNavigate();
    const {id} = useParams()
    const [dataBase, setDataBase]=useState()
    const [songDB,setSongDB] = useState([])
    const [count,setCount] =useState(0) 
    // var dataBase = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7]
    const [Url,setUrl] = useState()
    useEffect(()=>{
        const PlaylistCollectionRef = collection(db, "playlist")
        const fetchData = async ()=>{
            try{
                const q = query(PlaylistCollectionRef, where("PlaylistId", "==", id))
                const data = await getDocs(q)
                // const data = await getDocs(PlaylistCollectionRef)
                const filteredData = data.docs.map((doc)=>({...doc.data(), id:doc.id}))
                setDataBase(filteredData)
                if(filteredData){
                    filteredData[0].Songs.map((data,i)=> performDownload(data) )
                    console.log("FILTER",filteredData)
                }
                // handleDownload(filteredData[0].albumUrl)
            }catch(error){
                console.log(error)
            }    
        }
        fetchData()
    },[count])
    // const downloadSongData = async()=>{
        
    //     if(dataBase?.length > 0){
    //         console.log("DB :: ",dataBase)
    //         dataBase[0].Songs.map((data,i)=> performDownload(data) )
    //         console.log(dataBase[0]?.Songs)
    //     }
    // }
    const performDownload = async(songID)=>{
        const SongCollectionRef = collection(db, "music")
        const q = query(SongCollectionRef, where("SongId", "==", songID))
        const data = await getDocs(q)
        // const data = await getDocs(PlaylistCollectionRef)
        const filteredData1 = data.docs.map((doc)=>({...doc.data(), id:doc.id}))
        songDB.push({
            filteredData1
        })
        console.log("SONG DB",songDB)
        console.log("SONG NAME",songDB[0]?.filteredData1[0].SongName)

    }

    

    return(
        <div className="playlist-wrapper" id='playlist-id'>
            <div className="playlist-navbar">
                <Navbar/>
            </div>
            <div className="playlist-main">
                <div className="playlist-main-section-1">
                    <div className="playlist-main-section-1-subsection">
                    <div className="playlist-section-1-back">
                        <button>BACK</button>
                    </div>
                    <div className="playlist-section-1-front">
                        <div className="playlist-subsection-images">
                            <div className="playlist-img-box">
                                <img src={album} alt="" />
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div className="playlist-subsection-controls">
                            <div className="playlist-subsection-controls-name">
                                <h1>MY PLAYLIST</h1>
                            </div>
                            <div className="playlist-subsection-controls-control">
                                <button>Play</button>
                                <button>Add</button>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div className="playlist-main-section-2">
                    <div className="playlist-playlist-subsection">

                        {
                            dataBase ?
                            dataBase[0].Songs.map((data,i)=>
                                <SongDetail 
                                    playlistId = {id}
                                    albumId = {data.albumId}
                                    num = {i+1}
                                    name = {songDB[i*2]?.filteredData1[0].SongName}
                                />
                            )
                            : "LOADING" 
                        }
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    )
}
export default Playlist
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Once you go to `setDataBase()` setter function, your component should re-render with a new state value, are you sure that you are getting the right results after mapping on `data.docs` ?
The second thing that can cause your problem is that in `performDownload()` function you are modifying the state directly by pushing filtered results to the songDB state and the results of this operation will be not visible in the app UI, you should use `setSongDB` setter to make your data fully reactive.
Answering the question- in order to load your data before browser prints out the screen you can use useLayoutEffect hook: https://react.dev/reference/react/useLayoutEffect, but I think it's not necessary in your case. Check the results of your data fetching if they are in correct/awaited format and then use state setters to update a state.

Comment: Thank You, you were right I shouldn't have updated the state directly as it was causing the major problem. I didn't knew the appropriate way to do it in react  so used the js way to do it. This solved the entire issue. Once again thanks for helping me out.